# Add email send at specified interval to python script

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I have two python scripts that both work independently.  One logs some data to a log file and the other sends an email to a specified email address. I need to combine these two scripts together so that the email will send the log file at a specified interval.

I have managed to get both scripts working on there own but am not sure how to combine them into one working script.

script 1

```
def get_titles():
    current_title = None
    while True:
        moment2 = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y [ %H:%M:%S ]")
        new_title = GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow())
        if new_title != current_title:
           if len(new_title) > 0:
                #logging.info(" Moved to : " + new_title)
                current_title = new_title
                time.sleep(0.1)
                #print(new_title)
                ff= (moment2 + " : " +  "Moved T0 : "+ new_title + '\n')
                #print (ff)
                with open('logfile.txt', 'a+') as f:
                  f.write(ff)
```

script 2

```
body = "Please see attatched file for info"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

filename = "logfile.txt"
attachment = open("logfile.txt", "rb")

part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+filename)

msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtpname', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, password)
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

Comment: i have managed to get it working using the threading.Timer(300, send_msg).start().  But just a small problem now, a soon as the script is run, it sends a blank log file to the email, before any details are logged, but after the 300second interval it will send a log file with appended info.  is there any way to stop the first blank file being sent?

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 classes then call appropriate methods? Below is a rough template.

```
class LogData:
    def __init__():
        print("Initilized!")

    def get_titles():
        #write to log file
        ...
        ...
        ...
        return log_file_name

class SendEmail:
    def __init__(data_file):
        self.data_file = data_file

    def send_email():
        #read self.data_file and send email
        ...
        ...
        ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log = LogData()
    log_file = log.get_titles()
    email_handler = SendEmail(log_file)
    email_handler.send_email()
```

Comment: I have added the email script into the same file of the logging script, so would this be easier, than calling for the other self.data_file?  how owuld it be possible to send the email say every hour?